# Error when checking model target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 29430) but got array with shape (1108, 1)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I'm a bit new to Keras and I'm trying to create a model with the right dimensions. My training data is shaped such that `len(x_train)` = 1108 and `len(x_train)[0]` = 29430, but I seem to be making the shape incorrectly. (The exact error message in the title is at the place labeled with stars ***.)

I ran a model summary, so the shapes should be like this:

```
Layer (type) 
Output Shape          
Param #     
Connected to                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_1 (InputLayer)             
(None, 29430)         
0    
[nothing]                                       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  
(None, 64)            
1883584     
input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  
(None, 29430)         
1912950     
dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

```
inputs = Input(shape=(29430, ))
h = Dense(64, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
outputs = Dense(29430)(h)

model = Model(input=inputs, output=outputs)

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, # ***
    batch_size=batch,
    #epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    callbacks=[TestCallback((x_test, y_test))])

h.trainable = False

outputs = Dense(1)(h)
outputs = Activation('sigmoid')

model2 = Model(input=inputs, output=outputs)

model2.fit(x_train, y_train,
batch_size=batch,
epochs=epochs,
validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: What is the dimensionality of your features? 1108?

Comment: The number of features (or columns) is 29430, while the number of rows is 1108.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in the labels you provide to train the model. They are shape `(None, 1)` but the output of your model is `(None, 29430)` so the labels should have the same output.

Comment: No, the model has a scalar output.

Comment: Well, but the output is defined as `outputs = Dense(29430)(h)` so it has 29430 output units.

Comment: @gcucurull That would make sense. My labels are of the form [1, 1, ..., 0, 0] with 1108 elements. (Each row is labeled as a 1 or 0.) What would be your recommendation for modifying the label format and/or the model to fix the dimensions?

Comment: @gcucurull Ah I see my confusion, there are two models in the source code.

Comment: Yes you have two models, the last one does have only one output, but because you are calling `model.fit()` with the first model keras is trying to train the first model with the scalar labels.