# ValueError Tensor is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am having a bad time. While I was able to solve the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994524/keras-cnn-dimension-problems) I had with the dimensionality... new error appeared.

The task is still binary image segmentation. I have images of size WxH as well as labels of the same size (0, 255). I rescale images and labels to the values between (0,1) in the imageDataGenerator.

I followed [the advice](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1169) and reshaped my labels into `(None, W*H, 2)` using [this](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/18/image-segmentation-with-tensorflow-using-cnns-and-conditional-random-fields/) nice blog entry as a reference.

For the up-sampling I used [BilinearUpsampling2D](https://github.com/aurora95/Keras-FCN/blob/master/utils/BilinearUpSampling.py).

SO. My labels and the output of the network are of the same shape.

The error I am getting now is:

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("conv2d_1_input:0", shape=(?, 352, 128, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I am again posting the entire code and ask you if you notice any stupid things I am doing. I can't seem to figure it out.
Using Python3.5, Keras (2.1.2) with tensorflow (1.4.0) backend.

```
def superGenerator(image_gen, label_gen,batch):
    while True:
        x = image_gen.next()[0]
        y = label_gen.next()[0]
        #process label
        class_labels_tensor = K.equal(y, 1.0)
        background_labels_tensor = K.not_equal(y, 1.0)
        bit_mask_class = K.eval(tf.to_float(class_labels_tensor))
        bit_mask_bckg = K.eval(tf.to_float(background_labels_tensor))

        forg = numpy.reshape(bit_mask_class, (-1, bit_mask_class.shape[1]*bit_mask_class.shape[2]))
        bckg = numpy.reshape(bit_mask_bckg, (-1, bit_mask_bckg.shape[1]*bit_mask_bckg.shape[2]))

        label = numpy.stack((forg,bckg),axis=2)
        #label shape = (-1, 45056, 2), network output as well. 
        yield x, label


img_height = 352
img_width = 128

train_data_dir = 'dataset/Train/Images'
train_label_dir = 'dataset/Train/Labels'
validation_data_dir = 'dataset/Validation/Images'
validation_label_dir = 'dataset/Validation/Labels'
n_train_samples = 1000
n_validation_samples = 400
epochs = 25
batch_size = 5

input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 1)
target_shape = (img_height, img_width)
model = Sequential()


#Layer 1

model.add(Conv2D(80,(11,11), input_shape=input_shape, padding='same',  activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))

#Layer 2
model.add(Conv2D(96,(7,7), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))

#Layer 3
model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))

#Layer 4
model.add(Conv2D(160,(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

#FC Layer 1
model.add(Conv2D(1024, (1,1), activation='relu'))

#FC Layer 2
model.add(Conv2D(512, (1,1), activation='relu'))

#Classification layer
model.add(Conv2D(2, (1,1)))

#Bilinear upsampling
model.add(BilinearUpSampling2D(target_size=(img_height, img_width)))

#Softmax
model.add(Conv2D(2, (1,1), activation='softmax'))

#Reshape, to match labels (batch, w*h, 2)
model.add(Reshape((img_height*img_width,2)))

model.summary()



model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

data_gen_args = dict(
    rescale= 1./ 255,
    rotation_range=10,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    fill_mode='reflect',
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True
    )

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
train_label_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
test_label_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

seed = 5

train_image_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=target_shape,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=seed)
train_label_generator = train_label_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_label_dir,
    target_size=target_shape,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=seed)

validation_image_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=target_shape,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=seed)

validation_label_generator = test_label_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_label_dir,
    target_size=target_shape,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=seed)

train_generator = superGenerator(train_image_generator,   train_label_generator,batch_size)
test_generator = superGenerator(validation_image_generator, validation_label_generator,batch_size)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch= n_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=25,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps=n_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
model_yaml = model.to_yaml()
with open("model.yaml", "w") as yaml_file:
yaml_file.write(model_yaml)
```

Adding complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1070, in _run
allow_operation=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3348, in as_graph_element
return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3427, in _as_graph_element_locked
raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("conv2d_1_input:0", shape=(?, 352, 128, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ObjectNet.py", line 169, in <module>
validation_steps=n_validation_samples // batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 1227, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2147, in fit_generator
class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1839, in train_on_batch
outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2357, in __call__
**self.session_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1073, in _run
+ e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("conv2d_1_input:0", shape=(?, 352, 128, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
Exception ignored in: <function WeakValueDictionary.__init__.<locals>.remove at 0x7fb886217620>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 117, in remove
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error? Do try to reduce your problem to a [mcve], and post the full traceback.

Comment: I have no idea where the problem occurs. Added the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0):

For people having similar problems. I found the error from Keras very unintuitive. In my case there was no bug or errors with the layers.

My mentor pointed out, that this might be a problem of feeding the network with data of improper shape. This was not the case, since the outputs and inputs were ok.

The problem was in the choice of loss function and the shape it expects. I am still trying to figure out which loss function to use, but what I found to be working is either `dice coefficient loss` or `mean_pairwise_squared_error`.